# TravisCI: How to allow failures for environment variable

Tags: travis-ci

How to allow failures for builds having specific environment variable value?

For example:

.travis.yml:

```
env:
  - TEST_GROUP=Smoke
  - TEST_GROUP=other # How to allow failures for this variable?
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - TEST_GROUP=other # This does not work
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to explicitly reference `env` in the `allow_failures` section:

```
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - env: TEST_GROUP=other
```

Answer (score 12):

@roidrage's answer works for me.

When using multiple env variables in a single matrix dimension, env variables have to be combined like this:

```
env:
- TEST_GROUP=Smoke TEST_ENV=airport
- TEST_GROUP=other TEST_ENV=outside
matrix:
  allow_failures:
  - env: TEST_GROUP=other TEST_ENV=outside
```

Comment: If your env var line is getting too long you can do `env: >-` to be able to move each variable on a new line. Then to add a new matrix configuration you need to add multiple `>-`.